# How to change URLs in over 1000 Word documents efficiently?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, document, word

Is there any way to change URLs in over 1000 Microsoft Word documents efficiently? The documents are stored in a SharePoint 2013 library. Most URLS start with http://... but some others have a label / display name with a URL  behind it e.g. click 'here', where 'here' points to a URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can map the document library as Network Drives, then access the documents in network drives and using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll to modify the Urls in word files.

The following articles for your reference.

[Map SharePoint Online/On-Premises Document Libraries As Network Drives](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/map-sharepoint-onlineonpremises-document-libraries-as-network-drives)

[How To Access Network Drive Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp)

[How to open and edit a Word DOC or DOCX file from FileSystem or Byte array in C#](https://www.ryadel.com/en/open-edit-word-doc-docx-file-byte-array-c-msword-interop/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. You have been very helpful.